# I can't view WhatsApp media images in WhatsApp Private folder and Gallery

Tags: android, image, filesystems, whatsapp

I am using Samsung Galaxy 7s Edge Android version 8.0.

There are some images in my WhatsApp chat which are visible in Open WhatsApp -> Open the chat -> Click on 3 dots on the right upper corner ->  Media, links, and docs, here I can see those images

When I click on the image and then click on View media in gallery, I can see it.

When I click on Show in chat, I can see it in chat.

But when I close WhatsApp and go to Gallery, I cannot find it.

Also, When I go to My Files -> Internal Storage -> WhatsApp -> Media -> Private, I cannot find it.

Where are those images stored in my device?